# Can't build golang project with absolute package path

Tags: go, github, package, travis-ci, absolute-path

I am struggling with my travis-ci build.
Here the arborescence of my project:

```
- github.com
  - src
    - MyLib
      - MyLibImpl.go
     - main.go
```

The main.go is referencing MyLib like this

```
package main

import "fmt"
import MyLib "github.com/hako910/GolangTest/src/MyLib"

func main() {
    fmt.Printf("%v", MyLib.HelloWorld())
}
```

It works great on my machine but fails in travis-ci with this message:

```
$ go get -t -v ./...
github.com/hako910/GolangTest (download)
package github.com/hako910/GolangTest/src/MyLib: /home/travis/gopath/src/github.com/hako910/GolangTest exists but /home/travis/gopath/src/github.com/hako910/GolangTest/.git does not - stale checkout?

The command "eval go get -t -v ./... " failed. Retrying, 2 of 3.
```

Here is my source code https://github.com/hako910/GolangTest and here is my travis-ci build https://travis-ci.org/hako910/GolangTest/jobs/348845103

What is wrong with my configuration?

Comment: This is a bad habit (in Go) to put sources into the src directory, and this is the cause of your problem. At least, one go file must be located in the root directory. Useful information you can find here https://golang.org/doc/code.html and here https://blog.golang.org/organizing-go-code

Comment: @Illia Danko you are right
I moved the files out of src and it worked.